# строчки дублируют друг друга, нужно вынести в функцию

Tags: python

только начинаю питон изучать, никак не может дойти как в функцию вывести

```
timeline = input("Есть ли свободный график (да / нет): ");
premium_vakancia = input("Является ли данная вакансия премиум-вакансией (да / нет): ");

if timeline == 'да': timeline = True;
elif timeline == 'нет': timeline = False;

if premium_vakancia == 'да': premium_vakancia = True;
elif premium_vakancia == 'нет': premium_vakancia = False;

print(f'{timeline} ({type(timeline).__name__})\n'
  f'{premium_vakancia} ({type(premium_vakancia).__name__})');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timeline = (timeline == 'да')
premium_vakancia = (premium_vakancia == 'да')
```